# Possible to write test for controller without $httpbackend?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Im trying to understand Angularjs. I have a controller that contains one function and one http.get. Is it possible to write a Karma unittest for the function without mocking $httpbackend? Right now i get the error unexpected http call and the test newer runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `angular-mocks.js`, which I assume you are as you're using Karma, $httpBackend  [is already mocked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). You just need to define your expectations, which can be very loose. Like so:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/expected-url').respond(200, '');
```

If you want to use the *real* $httpBackend, don't include ngMock, but I won't recommend that :)